In MySQL how do you make a VIEW that has Columns generated from the values of a table
tldr: What is the code for the view that will take the results of a select statement and make those into additional columns?
Context:
I have 4 tables that I want to feed into a view to show sensor data,
Locations         [ID, NAME, ...Details(TBD)]
Parameters        [ID, NAME, Units]
Record (instance) [ID, Location_ID, Timestamp(Unix)]
Data              [Record ID, Parameter ID, Value]

I do not know how many sensors I will have (or add later) which is solved by the location table and joining on the LOCATION_ID
On the same logic I don't know how many datapoints each sensor will produce so the Parameter table gives me my extra columns (theoretically)
the View I can currently make is
Overview          [Location, Timestamp, Parameter, Value]

the View I want to make
Overview          [Locationn, Timestamp, Parameter1.value(As Parameter1),...,ParmeterN.value(as ParameterN)]

Example
Locations  [ [1,zoneA,...],[2,zoneB,...]...]
Parameter  [ [1,Temperature, Degrees],[2,Pressure,Bar],...]
Record     [ [1,1,1726257000],[2,2,1726257000],[3,1,1726257500],[4,2,1726257500]...]
Data       [ [1,1,80.0],[1,2,200],[2,1,79],[2,2,220],...]

Overview 1 [ [zoneA,1726257000,Temperature,80],
-            [zoneA,1726257000,Pressure,200],
-            [zoneB,1726257000,Temperature,79],
-            [zoneB,1726257000,Pressure,220,...],...]


Overview 2 [ [zoneA,1726257000,80,200,...],
-            [zoneB,1726257000,79,220,...],...]

Code:
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         127.0.0.1
-- Server version:               8.0.32 - MySQL Community Server - GPL
-- Server OS:                    Win64
-- HeidiSQL Version:             12.8.0.6908
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

-- Dumping structure for table air_quality.data
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `INSTANCE_ID` int NOT NULL,
  `PARAMETER_ID` int NOT NULL,
  `VALUE` char(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`INSTANCE_ID`,`PARAMETER_ID`),
  KEY `data_FK_PARAMETER_ID` (`PARAMETER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `data_FK_INSTANCE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`INSTANCE_ID`) REFERENCES `instance` (`INSTANCE_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `data_FK_PARAMETER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`PARAMETER_ID`) REFERENCES `parameter` (`PARAMETER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Data exporting was unselected.

-- Dumping structure for view air_quality.demo
-- Creating temporary table to overcome VIEW dependency errors
CREATE TABLE `demo` (
    `Location` CHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `UNIX_TIME` INT NOT NULL,
    `Parameter` CHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `Value` CHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

-- Dumping structure for table air_quality.instance
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `instance` (
  `INSTANCE_ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LOCATION_ID` int NOT NULL,
  `UNIX_TIME` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`INSTANCE_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `LOCATION_ID_UNIX_TIME` (`LOCATION_ID`,`UNIX_TIME`),
  CONSTRAINT `instance_FK_LOCATION_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`LOCATION_ID`) REFERENCES `location` (`LOCATION_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Data exporting was unselected.

-- Dumping structure for table air_quality.location
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `location` (
  `LOCATION_ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` char(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LOCATION_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `NAME` (`NAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Data exporting was unselected.

-- Dumping structure for table air_quality.parameter
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parameter` (
  `PARAMETER_ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` char(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `UNITS` char(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PARAMETER_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `NAME` (`NAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- Data exporting was unselected.

-- Removing temporary table and create final VIEW structure
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `demo`;
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `demo` AS select `location`.`NAME` AS `Location`,`instance`.`UNIX_TIME` AS `UNIX_TIME`,`parameter`.`NAME` AS `Parameter`,`data`.`VALUE` AS `Value` from (((`instance` join `location` on((`instance`.`LOCATION_ID` = `location`.`LOCATION_ID`))) join `data` on((`instance`.`INSTANCE_ID` = `data`.`INSTANCE_ID`))) join `parameter` on((`data`.`PARAMETER_ID` = `parameter`.`PARAMETER_ID`)));

/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=IFNULL(@OLD_TIME_ZONE, 'system') */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IFNULL(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, 1) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_NOTES, 1) */;

